# ASP.NET Core: IConfigurationBuilder Does Not Contain Definition For AddAzureKeyVault

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault, asp.net-core-2.1

I am upgrading my ASP.NET Core web app to .NET Core 2.1, but am getting the following error:

> IConfigurationBuilder Does Not Contain Definition For AddAzureKeyVault

This code works in .NET Core 2.0. It looks like a library is missing in .NET Core 2.1.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault;

namespace MyNamesace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
                    {
                        var keyVaultEndpoint = GetKeyVaultEndpoint();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
                        {
                            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                            var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

                            builder.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
                        }
                    })
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
        }

        static string GetKeyVaultEndpoint() => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyVaultEndpoint");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Answer

Install the [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault/) NuGet Package.

No changes to the code are necessary.

**UPDATE:** The `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault` NuGet Package has been deprecated. The new NuGet Packages is [Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets).

## Explanation

ASP.NET Core 2.0 template used the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.All](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/) NuGet package which includes the Azure Key Vault extensions for IConfiguration, but ASP.NET Core 2.1 template uses [Microsoft.AspNetCore.App](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/) which does not include the extension library.

## Code

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
                    {
                        var keyVaultEndpoint = GetKeyVaultEndpoint();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
                        {
                            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                            var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

                            builder.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
                        }
                    })
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
        }

        static string GetKeyVaultEndpoint() => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyVaultEndpoint");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault` has since been deprecated.

Comment: `Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets` is the NuGet package to be installed as `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault`  is deprecated now.

Comment: A mistake I made is to try to call `AddAzureKeyVault` on a `IConfiguration`.  It must be a `ConfigurationManager` (from the builder property `.Configuration`)